# Why does Clementine take minutes to open rather than seconds?

Tags: clementine

Whenever I open Clementine by double clicking an audio file or clicking the icon in Applications, it seems to take forever to open.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 on a Dell i5 pc.

Comment: If you're not using the libraries it requires; they'll need to be loaded as well (thus it's more efficient on some desktops that others; it's a Qt5 based program don't forget; the default Ubuntu Desktop is GNOME thus GTK3 based) - https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/clementine

Comment: Even then, it should not take minutes. Launch it from the terminal: the output there may reveal if something is wrong and what.

Comment: Does that mean Clementine won't open quickly on Ubuntu Desktop? I updated to Ubuntu 21.04 yesterday but no change to Clementine opening slowly. The icon displays after about 30 secs and Clementine opens about 30 secs after that.

Comment: How do I open it in Terminal? I opened Terminal and entered 'Clementine' but got loads of code I don't understand.